# i have a large hash and i want to get specific values in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

So i have this large Hash :

```
> {"queryCost"=>1,
 "latitude"=>43.1232321,
 "longitude"=>59.3123213,
 "resolvedAddress"=>"43.1232321,59.3123213",
 "address"=>"43.1232321,59.3123213",
 "timezone"=>"Asia/Samarkand",
 "tzoffset"=>5.0,
 "days"=>[{"datetime"=>"2022-03-30",
  "datetimeEpoch"=>1648580400,
  "source"=>"obs"},
  "hours"=>
   [{"datetime"=>"00:00:00",
     "datetimeEpoch"=>1648580400,
     "source"=>"obs"},
    {"datetime"=>"01:00:00",
     "datetimeEpoch"=>1648584000,
     "source"=>"obs"},
    {"datetime"=>"02:00:00",
     "datetimeEpoch"=>1648587600,
     "source"=>"obs"},
    {"datetime"=>"03:00:00",
     "datetimeEpoch"=>1648591200,
     "source"=>"obs"},
    {"datetime"=>"04:00:00",
     "datetimeEpoch"=>1648594800,
     "source"=>"obs"},
    {"datetime"=>"05:00:00",
     "datetimeEpoch"=>1648598400,
     "source"=>"obs"},
    {"datetime"=>"06:00:00",
     "datetimeEpoch"=>1648602000,
     "source"=>"obs"}]},
```

What i want is to get all hours that are 24, i can get them manually 1 by 1, using this hash_json['days'][0]['hours'][0]['datetime] and so on chaning 0 to 24, but how can i do a loop that gets me something like this :

loop through hash

puts hash hours datatime

end

output:
"00:00:00"
"01:00:00"
... until it gets "24:00:00" that is the last one.

I did see some examples but they where to simple, to use them on this hash, and since im new to ruby i cant rearly get it.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a few of the things you have tried that didn't work?

Comment: date = hash['days']['datetime'] but it says no implicit conversion from nil to string
or date = hash['days']['hours']['datetime] same but  string to integer

Comment: `hash["days"]` is an **array** of hashes. Which day is that you actually want? The first? The last? All of them? And which hour is it that you want as its also an array?

Comment: If you wanted to get the first of both days and hours you could do it in a nil safe way with `hash.dig("days", 0, "hours", 0, "datetime")`.

Comment: i need all of them

Comment: @max, imo, `dig` should not be used when (as here) the structure of the hash is known. That's because if the structure of a given hash is incorrect `hash["days"][0]["hours"][0]["datetime"]` will raise an exception that pinpoints the problem (what we want), whereas `dig` merely returns `nil`. One could of check if `dig` returns `nil`, but what's the point, as the problem needs to be fixed and by using `nil` we must track down the source of the problem?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree fully that dig is not the right answer here - parsing this structure should most likely be split into multiple methods / objects. But that longer answer requires that we actually know what the desired output is will most likely just go straight over the head of someone that hasn't figured out basic data structures.

Comment: @CodrinM this question is very hard to actually answer without a workable example of the desired result. `I just want to save the day and hours in a variable something like : day = 2022-03-30 hour = 00:00:00` implies that you just want one single result. But "i need all of them" says something completely different. Its also very hard to figure out what part of this your struggling with- is it the difference between hashes and arrays? How to iterate accross an array?

Comment: @max so lets say i want `puts hash['days'][0]['hours][0]['datetime'] hash['days'][0]['hours[1]['datetime']` .... 
how can i make it to be a loop that gets till last one ?

Comment: Can you please edit the question itself and provide an actual clear and unambigous example of the data that you want? As in the actual hash/array that you want returned.

Comment: ...and when editing your question please take a machete to your hash. You can remove 95%+ of the lines without changing the its essential structure. If it cannot be read without vertical scrolling it's unnecessarily large for the purpose of the question.

Comment: @max okey edited, sorry if i explained myself wrong, english is not my first language

Comment: I suggest you read about `each` and `map`.

Comment: No appology needed. But your english is not really the problem - its that you need to learn to communicate like a programmer. When giving an example of the output don't do it by describing it in words - thats almost never clear enough no matter how good your english is. Give an actual example as code. For example `["00:00:00", "01:00:00", "02:00:00"...]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do too much all at once with `hash_json['days'][0]['hours'][0]['datetime]`. I suggest breaking this into smaller pieces. For example do `days = hash_json['days']`. Now you have a variable with simpler structure. In this case it is a list. You can get the first element with `days[0]` or loop over the list with `days.each` or `days.map`. I suggest you read about `each` and `map` to learn what they are good for and how they work.